# Angular cli proxy config is not working for local host?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, http

trying to call nodejs localhost which is running at `http://localhost:9001` using angular proxy config however i am not able to call the endpoint , any idea what i have implemented wrong in below code ?

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient , HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AdminService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private url = "/api/saveClients";

  saveClientJobs(data) {
    let options = this.createRequestOptions();
    console.log("Service", data);
    return this.http.post(this.url, data, {
      headers: options
    });
  }

  private createRequestOptions() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    });
    return headers;
  }
}
```

proxy.config.json

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:9001",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```

Comment: everything looks fine, maybe you misconfigured your backend routing ?

Comment: Can you try again using the `https-proxy-agent`.  https://angular.io/guide/build#using-corporate-proxy